# How to read a txt file in python and output a dictionary with associating each word with a key outside txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm reading a txt file which is of form

```
apple, 1234, 156789086654, cat, John
orange, 7654, 8268249252745, dog, Smith
mango, 3467, 8328627427, cow, Alice
```

I have a dictionary of key_fields associating keys with value type

```
key_fields = { fruit : str
               num   : int
               date  : long
               animal : str
               name   : str }
```

I want to create a final dictionary from txt file and key_fields, where each attribute from each line in txt file is mapped to the key_fields like this, with appropriate type of value fields matching the dict key_fields -

```
{ fruit: "apple", num : 1234, date : 156789086654, animal : "cat", name : "John" }
{ fruit: "orange", num: 7654, date: 8268249252745, animal : "dog", name : "Smith"}
{ fruit: "mango", num: 3467, date : 8328627427, animal: "cow", name: "Alice" }
```

Comment: your dictionaries are not valid python dictionaries nor json valid ones.

Answer (score 0):

As an example with just one entry:

```py
line_1 = "apple, 1234, 156789086654, cat, John"

key_fields = { 
    "fruit": str,
    "num": int,
    "date": int,
    "animal": str,
    "name": str
}

result_dict = {key: builder(data) for ((key, builder), data) in zip(key_fields.items(), line_1.split(", "))}
```

[Playground](https://www.online-python.com/CaY9subvZF)